# Explanation of this line from A Christmas Carol

Tags: meaning

> The grocer and his people were so frank and fresh that the polished hearts with which they fastened their aprons behind might have been their own, worn outside for general inspection, and for Christmas daws to peck at if they chose.
>   (Charles Dickens, A Christmas Carol)

What is the *general inspection*? Was there something like an inspector to go around and  check if they wear their apron?

What does "for christmas daws to peck at it if they chose" mean?

Comment: Let me repeat myself: Please give a title that includes the problem, not a generic “I need help” or “I don’t understand this”. Use the [edit] button to clarify. Thanks!

Comment: And while you are editing, format the text from the book as “quote”, just put a ‘>’ in front. (Or use the icon.

Comment: Please include the clause before this one.

Comment: **hearts** is here the antecedent noun.  Their own [hearts]. An ellipsis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*General inspection* does not refer to some inspector walking around, but simply means *for all to see*.

*General* here has the same meaning as in *general public*, and *inspection* just means the act of *looking at something*.

According to some sources, this is a reference to Shakespeare's *Othello*:

> But I will wear my heart upon my sleeve
>   For daws to peck at: I am not what I am.

In [this pdf](http://drbacchus.com/files/christmas_carol/glossary.pdf) we find the following explanation for the daws and the meaning of wearing one's heart "outside":

> Daws, aka Jackdaws, are a kind of bird, related to crows.
>   The line in Othello, and here [*in A Christmas Carol*], refers to honesty and openness - the wearing of one’s true character in the open for everyone to see.

Basically, Charles Dickens is describing that the grocer and his people were very pure of heart. They used shiny heart-shaped fastenings on their apron, and Dickens sees in those polished hearts a symbol of them showing very honestly who they are: very frank and fresh people.